# Natural sorting using ​MySQL only

Tags: php, mysql

I need your help​​.

We ​are ​developing one eCommerce project for client​ and now we need to do sorting of products using natural sort from MySQL.​​ (​​We cannot do​ sorting by sorting array with PHP​ by using ​natsort, ​​because we are using lazy loading so we have to sort data from MySQL only)

​Need solution something like below example (But from MySQL)​

http://php.net/manual/en/function.​​natsort.php​

For More clarity: this is my Raw data which I want to sort.

```
    INSERT INTO `sample` (`id`, `data`) VALUES
(1, 'MLB-1.0-6.0-2.5'),
(2, 'MLB-1.0-6.0-3'),
(3, 'MLB-1.0-7.0-2'),
(4, 'MLB-1.0-7.0-2.5'),
(5, 'MLB-1.0-7.0-3'),
(6, 'MLB-1.0-9.0-2.5'),
(7, 'MLB-1.0-10.0-2'),
(8, 'MLB-1.0-10.0-2.5'),
(9, 'MLB-1.0-8.0-3'),
(10, 'MLB-1.0-9.0-2.5'),
(11, 'MLB-1.0-10.0-2'),
(12, 'MLB-1.0-10.0-2.5'),
(13, 'MLB-1.0-10.0-3'),
(14, 'MLB-1.0-12.0-2.5'),
(15, 'MLB-1.0-12.0-3'),
(16, 'MLB-1.2-10.0-2'),
(17, 'MLB-1.2-10.0-3'),
(18, 'MLB-1.2-10.0-4'),
(19, 'MLB-1.2-10.0-5'),
(20, 'MLB-1.2-11.2-2'),
(21, 'MLB-1.2-11.2-3'),
(22, 'MLB-1.2-11.2-4'),
(23, 'MLB-1.2-12.0-2'),
(24, 'MLB-1.2-12.0-2.5'),
(25, 'MLB-1.2-12.0-3'),
(26, 'MLB-1.2-12.0-4'),
(27, 'MLB-1.2-12.0-5'),
(28, 'MLB-1.2-12.0-6'),
(29, 'MLB-1.2-12.0-8'),
(30, 'MLB-1.2-12.7-3'),
(31, 'MLB-1.2-14.0-2.5'),
(32, 'MLB-1.2-14.0-3'),
(33, 'MLB-1.2-4.0-2.5'),
(34, 'MLB-1.2-4.0-3'),
(35, 'MLB-1.2-5.0-2'),
(36, 'MLB-1.2-5.0-2.5'),
(37, 'MLB-1.2-5.0-3'),
(38, 'MLB-1.2-6.0-2'),
(39, 'MLB-1.2-6.0-2.5'),
(40, 'MLB-1.2-14.0-4'),
(41, 'MLB-1.2-14.0-5'),
(42, 'MLB-1.2-16.0-3'),
(43, 'MLB-1.2-16.0-4'),
(44, 'MLB-1.2-16.0-5'),
(45, 'MLB-1.2-19.0-3'),
(46, 'MLB-1.2-19.0-4'),
(47, 'MLB-1.2-22.0-3'),
(48, 'MLB-1.2-22.0-4'),
(49, 'MLB-1.2-6.0-3'),
(50, 'MLB-1.2-6.0-4'),
(51, 'MLB-1.2-6.0-5'),
(52, 'MLB-1.2-6.0-6'),
(53, 'MLB-1.2-7.0-2'),
(54, 'MLB-1.2-7.0-2.5'),
(55, 'MLB-1.2-7.0-3'),
(56, 'MLB-1.2-7.0-4'),
(57, 'MLB-1.2-8.0-2'),
(58, 'MLB-1.2-8.0-2.5'),
(59, 'MLB-1.2-8.0-2/2.5B'),
(60, 'MLB-1.2-8.0-3'),
(61, 'MLB-1.2-8.0-4'),
(62, 'MLB-1.2-8.0-5'),
(63, 'MLB-1.2-8.0-6'),
(64, 'MLB-1.2-8.0-8'),
(65, 'MLB-1.2-9.0-2'),
(66, 'MLB-1.2-9.0-2.5'),
(67, 'MLB-1.2-9.0-3'),
(68, 'MLB-1.2-9.0-4');
```

This is my expected result after sorting:

```
MLB-1.0-6.0-2.5
MLB-1.0-6.0-3
MLB-1.0-7.0-2
MLB-1.0-7.0-2.5
MLB-1.0-7.0-3
MLB-1.0-8.0-2
MLB-1.0-8.0-2.5
MLB-1.0-8.0-3
MLB-1.0-9.0-2.5
MLB-1.0-10.0-2
MLB-1.0-10.0-2.5
MLB-1.0-10.0-3
MLB-1.0-12.0-2.5
MLB-1.0-12.0-3
MLB-1.2-4.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-4.0-3
MLB-1.2-5.0-2
MLB-1.2-5.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-5.0-3
MLB-1.2-6.0-2
MLB-1.2-6.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-6.0-3
MLB-1.2-6.0-4
MLB-1.2-6.0-5
MLB-1.2-6.0-6
MLB-1.2-7.0-2
MLB-1.2-7.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-7.0-3
MLB-1.2-7.0-4
MLB-1.2-8.0-2
MLB-1.2-8.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-8.0-2/2.5B
MLB-1.2-8.0-3
MLB-1.2-8.0-4
MLB-1.2-8.0-5
MLB-1.2-8.0-6
MLB-1.2-8.0-8
MLB-1.2-9.0-2
MLB-1.2-9.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-9.0-3
MLB-1.2-9.0-4
MLB-1.2-10.0-2
MLB-1.2-10.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-10.0-3
MLB-1.2-10.0-4
MLB-1.2-10.0-5
MLB-1.2-11.2-2
MLB-1.2-11.2-3
MLB-1.2-11.2-4
MLB-1.2-12.0-2
MLB-1.2-12.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-12.0-3
MLB-1.2-12.0-4
MLB-1.2-12.0-5
MLB-1.2-12.0-6
MLB-1.2-12.0-8
MLB-1.2-12.7-3
MLB-1.2-14.0-2.5
MLB-1.2-14.0-3
MLB-1.2-14.0-4
MLB-1.2-14.0-5
MLB-1.2-16.0-3
MLB-1.2-16.0-4
MLB-1.2-16.0-5
MLB-1.2-19.0-3
MLB-1.2-19.0-4
MLB-1.2-22.0-3
MLB-1.2-22.0-4
```

Below solution already tried​:​
http://skybluesofa.com/blog/how-implement-natural-sorting-mysql/
http://www.copterlabs.com/natural-sorting-in-mysql/

Kindly suggest solutions for this using MySQL.

Comment: Provide the good people the db schema and expected results.

Comment: We need solution like this example but with MySQL. http://php.net/manual/en/function.​​natsort.php​

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data you posted, I think this will help:

```
SELECT *
FROM sample 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, '-', 2), 5) AS double),
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, '-', 3), '-', -1) AS double),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(`data`, '-', -1);
```

What the query does is to split the data column using `'-'` as a delimiter and extracting the numeric parts, i.e., from `''MLB-1.2-4.0-2.5'` extracts `1.2`, `4.0` and `2.5`, converts them to double (except the last chunk) and orders the data by them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [example](https://books.google.gr/books?id=Hg0H0s3WJSgC&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=mysql%20natural%20sort%20on%20string%20that%20also%20contains%20number&source=bl&ots=YKQjCvrIfp&sig=BRuquzsVElYJcm7Pe6kvrAhP2x4&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS9_qfy8DMAhUDApoKHY8gDX4Q6AEIbDAI#v=onepage&q=mysql%20natural%20sort%20on%20string%20that%20also%20contains%20number&f=false) and assuming that `data` column will have the format that you have posted, (a string that has 3 dashes as delimiter).

```
select *,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,"-",3),"-",-1) as mystring from sample ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,"-",2),"-",-1)+0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,"-",3),"-",-1)+0, SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,"-",-1);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/744793/6)